# Creating Multiple things upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#add').click(function () {
                $('#taskCont').append('<div class="task"></div>');
                $('.task').append('<input type="checkbox">', '<div></div>', '<small>Delete</small>');
                
            });
```

```css
.task{
  width : 200px;
  height : 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="add">add</p>
<div id="taskCont"></div>
```

Click on the add button multiple time. How can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending to `.task` each time which selects more divs as they are added. Instead, create a variable each time and append that.

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  let task = $('<div class="task"></div>')
  task.append('<input type="checkbox">', '<div></div>', '<small>Delete</small>')
  $('#taskCont').append(task)
});
```

```css
.task {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="add">add</p>
<div id="taskCont"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to append to the last task?

```
$('.task:last-of-type').append(
```

Comment: i got my answer.